# Почему в шаблоне remove_const отбрасывается константность?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие правила выведения типов и работы с типами используются в этих шаблонах, в результате чего получается удаление константности? Почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct type_is {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_const : type_is<T> {

};

template<typename T>
struct remove_const<const T> : type_is<T> {

};

template<typename U, typename V>
constexpr bool same = std::is_same_v<U, V>;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static_assert(same<remove_const<const int>::type, int>);

    return 0;
}
```

Как я понимаю, наследование используется для того, чтобы повторно не определять поле type. А какие правила выведения типов используются в декларации `using type = T`? Я сначала думал, что здесь отбрасывается константность, ссылочность и волатайлность, но оказалось, что это не так. Это псевдоним типа и константность здесь не отбрасывается. Каким образом поле `type` в специализации шаблона `remove_const` для `const T` отбрасывает константность? Почему она отбрасывается?

Comment: Ну так если встречается `const`, срабатывает специализация `struct remove_const<const T> : type_is<T> {` и `T` уже `const` не имеет...

Comment: Почему T уже конст не имеет? По какому правилу? Мы же специализируем шаблон типом const T, и получается что T = const T. Разве нет?

Comment: Вы путаете параметр шаблона `T` и параметр специализации шаблона с тем же именем. Если параметр шаблона будет `const int`, то параметр специализации будет просто `int`.

Comment: Количество, типы, имена и т.п. параметров специализации могут отличаться от их же у основного шаблона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеются

```
template<typename T> struct remove_const : type_is<T> {};
template<typename T> struct remove_const<const T> : type_is<T> {};
```

Рассмотрим на примере

```
remove_const<mytype>::type
```

Компилятор смотрит на оба варианта, видит, что для второго варианта он вообще не проходит, остается первый

```
template<typename T> struct remove_const : type_is<T> {};
```

в котором `T === mytype`. Значит,

```
remove_const<mytype>::type
```

превращается в `T`, т.е. просто `mytype`.

Теперь пусть у нас

```
remove_const<const mytype>::type
```

Компилятор смотрит на оба варианта, видит, что для первого варианта все работает при `T === const mytype`, а для второго при `T === mytype`. При этом второй вариант "более подходящий" (чтобы точно разобраться, почему и как — см. стандарт), так что выбирается он, с (tot раз напомню) `T === mytype`.

```
template<typename T> struct remove_const : type_is<T> {};
```

в котором `T === mytype`. Значит,

```
remove_const<const mytype>::type
```

как и ранее превращается просто в `T`,т.е. в `mytype`.

Так понятнее?

Answer (score 1):

Все проясняется, если давать параметрам осмысленные имена. А не поступать, как товарищ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком объявлении шаблона понятно, что параметром *шаблона* может быть тип с `const` квалификатором или без него.

```
template<typename TypeMaybeWithConst>
struct remove_const : type_is<TypeMaybeWithConst>
{};
```

Далее, при объявлении специализации понятно, что параметром *специализации* может быть просто тип, без квалификатора. При этом параметр *шаблона* указывается в угловых скобках после имени шаблона, как при инстанцировании. Т.е. параметром *шаблона* `TypeMaybeWithConst` тут будет `const JustType`

```
template<typename JustType>
struct remove_const<const JustType> : type_is<JustType>
{};
```

Далее, при инстанцировании шаблона `remove_const<const int>` параметром шаблона  `TypeMaybeWithConst` будет тип `const int`, а когда компилятор начнет выбирать подходящую специализацию, он попробует сопоставить параметр *шаблона* `const JustType` с фактическим параметром *шаблона* `const int` и после успешного сопоставления выведет параметр *специализации* `JustType` как `int`.